# Highlighting td elements with same values

Tags: jquery

I am using the following method to highlight specific td elements with same values. Adding a class to the td which works fine.

```
<table id='sample'>
    <tr>
    <td data-content="1">1</td>
    <td data-content="2">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td data-content="2">2</td>
    <td class="3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td class="2">2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.2').addClass('highlight1');
$('.3').addClass('highlight2');
```

Css:

```
.highlight1 {background-color:#9ac99d ; color:black}  
.highlight2 {background-color:#EC7063 ; color:black}
```

My question is if it is possible to use data-content tag in the td element without adding an extra class tag to the td elements?  Thanks.

here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/07ph2tj4/):

Comment: Ever used attribute selectors before?  Yes it's possible.  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I tried this. but didn't work. when i use attributes, I need to target a specific table. `.tableName td[data-content="2"]{
  background-color: ##B2BABB;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by attribute selector as below:

```
$("[data-content=2]").addClass('highlight1');
$("[data-content=3]").addClass('highlight2');
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lju57dyp/)

Comment: sure, I will. in about 6 minutes. it doesn't let me accept right now.